# distance between two functions by considering invariance

Tags: functional-analysis, invariance

For two functions $f(x): \mathbb R^n \mapsto \mathbb R^m$, $g(x): \mathbb R^n \mapsto \mathbb R^m$. An usual way to define their distance may be
$$
  \|f-g\| = \sqrt{\int_x \|f(x)-g(x)\|^2 dx}.
$$
I think we can prove this distance is a metric. Now suppose I allow linear invariance, *i.e.*:

> If there exists a matrix $W \in \mathbb R^{m \times m}$ such that for any $x$, $f(x) = W g(x)$, then the distance between $f$ and $g$ is zero.

How could I modify the definition of distance above to take care of this invariance? Can we still prove that the modified distance is also a metric?

Comment: You must require some conditions on $f$ and $g$, otherwise your integral might not make sense.

Comment: I assume they have to be $L^2(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$, so that your distance is just the one associate to the usual $L^2$-norm.

Comment: What you want by dividing by that equivalence class is called a [projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space). Natural metrics on projective spaces are angular in nature, so your current definition would not be a metric on the new space - [this answer explains why](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/421735/metric-and-measure-on-the-projective-space)

Comment: I see @NinadMunshi. This is quite helpful. Anyway, do you think $\min_W \| f - Wg\|$ a reasonable definition?

Comment: I have given an appropriate metric below as an answer that has the invariance you want. This describes an angular distance between "rays" in your space.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the intuition in projective spaces, the following would make a good metric for your new space

$$d(f,g) = \cos^{-1}\left[\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\hat{f}\cdot \hat{g}\:dx\right] = \cos^{-1}\left[\frac{\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}f\cdot g\:dx}{\sqrt{\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}||f||^2\:dx}\sqrt{\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}||g||^2dx}}\right]$$

where $\hat{f}$ and $\hat{g}$ are the chosen representatives of their equivalence classes with unit norm in the original space.

Comment: I could see that this definition is scale invariant. Although not fully address the linear invariant case, it's still very helpful.