# Construct an volume form on $\mathbb RP^n$ (n odd) using the antipodal map

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms, orientation

We have the volume form  $\mu=i^*(\omega)$ on $S^n$, where $$\omega=\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^{j-1}x_{j}dx_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge \hat{dx_{j}}\wedge\cdots dx_{n+1}$$ is a k-form on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ and $i:S^n\to \mathbb R^{n+1}$ is the inclusion.

Define the antipodal map $A:S^n\to S^n$ by $x \mapsto -x$. Indeed, $A^*(\mu)=(-1)^{n+1}\mu$. Does this gives us a volume form on $\mathbb R P^n$ for n odd? It seems we have the projection map $p:S^n\to  \mathbb R P^n$, but it's the wrong direction to pull back the form. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134836/riemannian-metric-in-the-projective-space/134843#134843) may be of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Pull back by local inverses of $p$, and use your computation to check that you get a well-defined form on $\Bbb RP^n$. Alternatively, define a form $\eta$ on $\Bbb RP^n$ by setting its value $\eta([x])(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ to be something in terms of $\mu$, and check that everything is well-defined.

Comment: Sorry to raise an old thread, but is the $\eta$ defined by $\eta([x])(v_1,\dots, v_n)=\mu(x)(z_1,\dots, z_n)$ where $\pi_*z_i=v_i$, and $\pi(x)=[x]$? Clearly there's no choice in $z_i$, but one can still show that if there was it's indepndent of the choice. Then using that, $\omega_{-x}=(F^*\omega)_x=(-1)^{n+1}\omega_x$ so it should work out right?

Comment: @Chris Of course there’s choice in the $z_i$. Compare $x$ and $-x$.

Comment: @TedShiffrin I meant once we’ve made a choice in $x$ there’s no choice in $z_i$ because the projection is a local diffeomorphism. I was thinking fix $x$ show the tangent vectors are independent of choice. Then show the $x$ is independent of choice.